# slick mobile scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, slick.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Product Carousel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
  
  <style>
    .slick-list {
      padding: 0 20% 0 0;
    }
    .slick-slider {
      touch-action: auto;
      -ms-touch-action: auto;
    }
    .card {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .card img {
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Eiffel-Tower.png" alt="Product 2">
      <h2>Product 2</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Taj-Mahal.png" alt="Product 3">
      <h2>Product 3</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Great-Wall-of-China.png" alt="Product 4">
      <h2>Product 4</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Statue-of-Liberty.png" alt="Product 5">
      <h2>Product 5</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Pyramids-of-Giza.png" alt="Product 6">
      <h2>Product 6</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Colosseum.png" alt="Product 7">
      <h2>Product 7</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Machu-Picchu.png" alt="Product 8">
      <h2>Product 8</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/Petra.png" alt="Product 9">
      <h2>Product 9</h2>
      <p>Description of Product 9</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script>

      $('.multiple-items').slick({
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 2.3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        useCSS: true,
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am planning to use it on mobile version but when i try on my mobile it dosent work smooth and it lags when changing slide what i am trying to achive is something similar to [example-1](https://www.thrillophilia.com/cities/abu-dhabi/things-to-do), [Example-2](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/scrollview/cards) [Example-3](https://uae.sharafdg.com/c/gaming/games/sony_ps4_games/?idx=products_index_price_asc&hFR%5Btaxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical%5D%5B0%5D=Gaming%20%3E%20Games%20%3E%20Sony%20PS4%20Games)

as you can see in these sites in mobile version scrolling is superfast

i tried changing few settings like `swipeToSlide: true,` but nothing seems to work

even slidestoshow is not working it shows 3 slides in mobile view although i have set to 2.3

i tried changing few settings like swipeToSlide: true, but nothing seems to work

even slidestoshow is not working it shows 3 slides in mobile view although i have set to 2.3